# Resolve an IContext with Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

i try to resolve an IContext with Ninject in this code. I have a ContextProvider which provide the DBContext which is inherited by MySampleContext.

```
protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest()
{
     ContextProvider cp = new ContextProvider();
     cp.SetCurrent(new MySampleContext());
}
```

Or would it be better that i keep it this way.. ? The problem is that i can'T access Kernel since its created in a bootstrap.

Any idea ? What i want to do is provide a context using ninject instead of instancing mySampleContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your Context in request scope and constructor inject it where ever you need it. This way it is only created when it is used somewhere.

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<MySampleContext>().InRequestScope();
```

In case you really need to set it on the ContextProvider then add an activation action

```
.OnActivation(i => new ContextProvider().SetCurrent(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If suggest your 2 solutions. If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could probably use the DepencyResolver

```
DepencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContext>();
```

Or you can also declare a static property in your MvcApplication (Global.asax) like

```
public static IKernel CurrentKernel {get;set;}
```

And in your bootstrapper where you init your Kernel

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
// Bindings here...
MvcApplication.CurrentKernel = kernel;
```

And if you get problems because your Kernel isn't bootstrapped yet in the BeginRequest, I suggest you to handle the following event instead of the BeginRequest

```
Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

The entire point of having an IDependencyResolver support DI and decouple your applications from the IoC you are using. If you ever have to refactor your code to use a different IoC (Structuremap for example) you wont have dependencies on Ninject all through out your code.

If you are in the situation where you cannot use constructor injection, you need to call the static DependencyResolver in System.Web.Mvc like so:

```
var context = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContext>();
```

Comment: This: `var context = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContext>();` is an example. The way it works is you register your interfaces and concrete implementations with Ninject `Bind<IContext>().To<MySampleContext>();` then you make the call like above to the DependencyResolver.

Comment: DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IContext>(); return NULL .. dunno what im doing wrong.. ive set the resolver.. in the bootstrap but still doesnt work.

Comment: You are going to have to show more code. How did you setup the bootstrapper? Is the bootstrapper getting called in the app start? Did you install Ninject via NuGet? If so, did you install the Ninject.MVC3? package?

Comment: The point of having a dependency resolver is to provide proper dependency injection to the application and not to have a service locator. There is almost no situation where you can't solve problems without service location.